# Unable to use webcams

Tags: 14.04, usb, webcam, lock

I have 3 webcams attached to my laptop for a c++/opencv project and my program crashed. Now it keeps giving warnings that "device or resource busy". I suspect this is a OS level error. Is there any way to forcibly unlock my webcams? I'm using 14.04.

So far I have disconnected and reconnected the device and tried to change the permission of `/dev/video0` `/dev/video1` and `/dev/video2` to `chmod 777`. I have also tried sudo lsof /dev/video0 which didn't work either:

```
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1000/gvf Output information may be incomplete.
```

I have also tried complete reboots of the laptop. The problem exists both in 2 usb connected webcams and 1 internal webcam.

Software updates haven't helped either and the problem has now been persisting for several days now. Anybody who has any good idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Some program is blocking it, try `sudo lsof /dev/video0`

Comment: That returns the following message: `lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1000/gvf Output information may be incomplete.` And the problem persists after this.

Comment: purge and reinstall the linux-headers-``uname -r ``